# Interpretation of "find packages tell people add your application"

Tags: sentence-meaning

https://youtu.be/x03fjb2VlGY?t=83

This video's subtitle says

> you can find packages tell people add your application by browsing the NPM website

I guess this sentence means:

> You can find packages, or you can tell people to add your application into their applications ..."

Could you tell me if I'm wrong or something is wrong in the subtitle?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on an error from auto-generated subtitles.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"You can find packages to help your application by browsing the NPM website."

Comment: Thanks! It sounds to me like "You can find packages to help **build** your application".